# Half of the scale value not in the middle

Tags: transforms, coordinates

I just tried starting with Blender by scaling a cube with the values x=20,y=20.
[image]

Afterwards I tried to move the bottom left corner to the origin by changing the location by half of the values (10,10) - but it's not at the origin afterwards.

[image]

Can anyone explain why and how to move it accordingly?

Thanks :)

Comment: the original cube is 2x2.  scaling it 20x20 makes it 40x40. so to move the corner to the origin you have to move it (20,20) not (10,10)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/why-is-blenders-default-cube-2-cubic-meters-instead-of-1

Answer (score 4):

So you had a cube that is 2x2x2 meters big. You scaled it 20 times in x and y axis so it got 40x40x2 meters big. Now you move it by 10 meters in x and 10 meters in y axis and it moves, but it's still 40x40 meters big in x and y axis and since it was in the center of your scene it still has 10 meters sticking out in -x and -y directions from the center.

Scale is a multiplier. If you want to input dimensions, use - not a big surprise there - dimensions input fields in the n panel:

[image]